# TFS Online - Dont Zip empty folder

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, build-process

We're using TFS-Online to One-Click-Deploy our Software.

From time to time it happens, that we need to use some special scripts, we store in a folder. This basically means, most of the time said folder stays empty.

If i now go and trigger a build, i have there followings tasks

[image: Zip task]

Now the question:

Is there any way to suppress these two tasks if the folder to be zipped/deleted is empty?

The tasks are the built in ones.

**Note**: This is NO on-premise TFS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could **specify conditions** for running a task in VSTS. Express the condition as a nested set of functions. The agent evaluates the innermost function and works its way out. The final result is a **boolean** value that determines if the task is run or not.

In your case, a solution should be:

- Add a powershell task prior to the Archive Files task.
- Use the powershell task to judge the folder is empty or not.
- If the folder is empty then fail the powershell task.(Remember to check *Continue on error* or *always run* option)
- Add a condition for both Archive File and Delete File task such as ***Only when all previous tasks have succeeded***

After this, those two task will not run when the special folder is empty during the build pipeline.

More details please refer this thread [Specify conditions for running a task](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/concepts/process/conditions).

Comment: Nice. Havent thought of this workaround. A pitty that there's no built in condition.